# pass variable from Backbone.js router initialize function to the forEach statement of another router function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, leaflet

**Please see updated code below...**

I am attempting to filter one [backbone](/questions/tagged/backbone) collection by the attributes of another collection using a forEach statement. How can I write this in order to maintain the reference to the variable "this.neighborhoodsCollection" within the forEach statement. This may be less of a [backbone](/questions/tagged/backbone) question and more of a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) question. I guess, in other words, how do I pass in the variable "this.neighborhoodsCollection" into my forEach statement. Here are the steps I am trying to take:

I pass the results of fetching my StoryCollection and NeighborhoodsCollection to the Router:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var neighborhoodsCollection = new NeighborhoodsCollection();
        neighborhoodsCollection.fetch({
            success: function(){
                var storyCollection = new StoryCollection();
                storyCollection.fetch({
                    success: function () {
                    var app = new AppRouter(neighborhoodsCollection, storyCollection);
                    Backbone.history.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Then I set the passed in arguments as local variables...

```
initialize: function(neighborhoodsCollection, storyCollection){
    this.neighborhoodsCollection = neighborhoodsCollection;
    this.storyCollection = storyCollection;

}
```

In another function within the router, I check the array of neighborhoods in the current storyCollection against every neighborhood attribute in the Neighborhoods collection, and if there is a match, I add the Neighborhoods collection object to my Leaflet map.

```
load_story:function (id) {
        //get Stories model object by id
        this.story = this.storyCollection.get(id);

var storyNeighborhoods = this.story.attributes.neighborhoods;

    storyNeighborhoods.forEach(function(neighborhood){

     var hood = this.neighborhoodsCollection.attributes;
     var nabe = [];
     var nabeGeo = [];


     for(var i = 0; i < _.size(hood); i++){
         nabe.push(this.neighborhoodsCollection.attributes[i].properties.neighborhood);

         nabeGeo.push(this.neighborhoodsCollection.attributes[i]);

         var filterNabe = $.inArray(neighborhood, nabe);

         if(filterNabe > -1){
            L.geoJson(nabeGeo).addTo(map);
         }else{
            console.log('not found')
         }
     }
 });
}
```

**UPDATE**

@Quince's answer set me on the right track, using pluck and intersection undescore helpers. Now I have an array containing every matching neighborhood string. Then I try to use that string to perform a get on the collection. Here is the data structure of my collection:

```
Object { cid: "c1", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object, _pending: false }
```

And here is the structure of the lone object in my collection:

```
[{ "id": "Greenpoint", "type": "Feature", "properties": { "neighborhood": "Greenpoint", "boroughCode": "3", "borough": "Brooklyn" ... }]
```

However I cannot successfully perform a get(id) on this collection. Maybe it has something to do with needing to create a model from each object in the collection, or something like that?

For reference, here is the relevant code based on @Quince example:

```
  var neighborhoodsCollection = this.neighborhoodsCollection;

var neighborhoodsCollectionObjects = this.neighborhoodsCollection.attributes;

var neighborhoodsCollectionProperties = _.pluck(neighborhoodsCollectionObjects, 'properties');

var neighborhoodsCollectionArray = _.pluck(neighborhoodsCollectionProperties, 'neighborhood');

var storyCollectionNeighborhoods = this.story.attributes.neighborhoods;

var neighborhoodIntersection = _.intersection(storyCollectionNeighborhoods, neighborhoodsCollectionArray);
```

The value of neighborhoodIntersection is an array that includes the single string "Greenpoint"

```
neighborhoodIntersection.forEach(function(neighborhood){
    neighborhoodsCollection.get(neighborhood);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understood this right, you want to look through each story and if it has a neighborhood that matches one of the neighborhoods form the main neighborhood collection then you want to grab a reference to it?

The way would go about this is to use underscores intersection function when comparing the id's in the story's neighborhood collection to the id's in the main neighborhood collection. Then use this list to grab the actual references from the main neighborhood collection. Below is an example of what i mean ([or the code pen so you can see in the console that the references are obtained](http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/wrLKH))

```
//setup of models and collections 
var NeighbourHoodModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name: null
  }
});

var StoryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    neighbourhoods:null
  }
});
var NeighborhoodsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: NeighbourHoodModel
});
var StoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: StoryModel
})

var neighbourHoods = new NeighborhoodsCollection([
  { id:1,name: "neighbourhood-1"},
  { id:2,name: "neighbourhood-2"},
  { id:3,name: "neighbourhood-3"},
  { id:4,name: "neighbourhood-4"}
]);

var stories = new StoryCollection([
  { id:1, neighbourhoods: new NeighborhoodsCollection([
      { id:1,name: "neighbourhood-1"},
      { id:2,name: "neighbourhood-2"}
     ]),
  },
  { id:2, neighbourhoods: new NeighborhoodsCollection([
      { id:1,name: "neighbourhood-1"},
      { id:2,name: "neighbourhood-2"}
     ]),
  }
]);

(function(neighbourHoods,stories){
  var _matchedNeighbourhoodIds = [];
  //grab an array (usign pluck) of all the nighboorhood ids
  //do this here so don;t have to do it on every loop
  var neighbourhoodIds = neighbourHoods.pluck("id");

  stories.forEach(function(story){

   //for each story grab an array (using pluck) of all the stories neighborhoods
   //perform an intersection of the two arrays (returning an array of id's that appear in both lists)
    //slice that array
    //for each element add it to the _matchNeighbourhoods in at a sorted index (this is so that we don't end with duplicates in the array)
    _.intersection(story.get("neighbourhoods").pluck("id"),neighbourhoodIds).slice(0).forEach(function(neighbourhoodId){
      _matchedNeighbourhoodIds[_.sortedIndex(_matchedNeighbourhoodIds,neighbourhoodId)] = neighbourhoodId;
    });
  });


  _matchedNeighbourhoodIds.forEach(function(matchedNeighbourHoodId){
         console.log(neighbourHoods.get(matchedNeighbourHoodId));
});

})(neighbourHoods,stories);
```

One problem i have just seen after making this is with _.sortedIndex, although the array contains only unique id's for the matchedNeighbourhoods, it is still taking the time to over-right the the values when already matched neighborhoods are added.

Comment: This really set me on the right track. Now I have an array containing every matching neighborhood string that I will use to perform a .get on the collection. This is where I run into trouble. I will add my current code to my question above as an update, and maybe you can take a look?

Comment: the structure of your neighbourhoods collection looks odd, is it a Backbone collection? as it looks more like a model. Normally this is what my collections look like if I log them                           r {length: 4, models: Array[4], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}

Comment: actually just also noticedyou use the line ---- var neighborhoodsCollectionObjects = this.neighborhoodsCollection.attributes; but if this was a collection and you wanted to grab the models from it you would use this.neighborhoodsCollection.models as a Backbone collection doesn't have attributes, so this is why the get won't work. you need have your neighbourhoods collections defined as a collection that has a neighbourhood model as it's model

Comment: Okay, I figured out my error, and of course, it's a careless mistake :(  I defined both my model and my collection as Backbone.Model.extend. Once I changed the collection variable to equal Backbone.Collection.extend the collection has the proper structure and @Quince answer is exactly what i needed. It was working just well enough to hide my mistake, until it wasn't, and I had to trace the error backwards to the very beginning.